# Find the convolution of $x(t)*h(t)$

Tags: improper-integrals, convolution

I am studying for an exam and have the following question:

$$x(t) = u(t)$$
$$h(t) = [e^{-t}-e^{-2t}]u(t)$$

where `u(t)` is a unit-step function. I need to find the convolution x(t)*h(t).

So:
$$
x(t)*h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(t)[e^{-t}-e^{-2t}]u(t-\tau)d\tau\
$$
$$
x(t)*h(t) = u(t)[e^{-t}-e^{-2t}]\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(t-\tau)d\tau\
$$

The question I have is how do I take the integral of 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(t-\tau)d\tau\
$$

And how would I graph this convolution? TIA!

Comment: You should check your definition of convolution; you might have swapped a $\tau$ with a $t$ somewhere :).

Comment: @NickThompson would I also put $$(t-\tau)$$ for $$e^{-t} - e^{-2t}$$

Comment: Nope: Check the definition of convolution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: @NickThompson Oh I think I see what you're saying now. I think this would be my correct equation then: $$
x(t)*h(t) = [e^{-t}-e^{-2t}]\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau\
$$

Comment: Not quite! Your exponents have the wrong argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your notation, 
\begin{align*}
(x\ast h)(t) &= \int_\mathbb{R} u(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau  \overset{\textrm{u is step function}}{=} \int_0^\infty h(t-\tau)d\tau \\ &= \int_0^\infty (e^{-(t-\tau)}-e^{-2(t-\tau)})u(t-\tau) d\tau \\ &= \int_0^t (e^{-(t-\tau)}-e^{-2(t-\tau)}) d\tau, \qquad t\geq 0 \\ &= \left( \frac{1}{2} - e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2}e^{-2t} \right) u(t)
\end{align*}
the key point is that $u(t-\tau)$ as a function of $\tau$ is $1$ for $\tau \leq t$ and zero otherwise (a graph with these transformations - first shift to the right, then invert sign- may help).

Comment: Awesome, this was super helpful! Thanks bbn!